# Range of values provided by user to replace values in existing file after a certain string

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I'm looking to change a python script which has these strings:

```
string_1=0.6
string_2=0.5
```

Would like to allow the user to provide a range of values to replace the existing ones in the file. It would be even better to let the user define starting, ending values and spacing. The idea at the end would be to run the python script multiple times and having those string values changed at each iteration.

I was thinking you could use sed for some find and replace with a user input defined variable but I'm clueless about lower/upper bound and spacing.

```
#/bin/bash
      
read -p "Insert value:" user_value
sed -i "s/string_1=/string_1=$user_value/g" file.py
```

I'm on mac.

Many thanks

EDIT: The script should ask the user to provide an initial value and an ending value (range) and an incremental parameter that would define the speed of the increase at each iteration. Eg:

```
 - User defined initial value:10
 - User defined ending value:20
 - User defined incremental value:1
```

The script will set up `string_1` to 10 as defined in the previous step and then proceed to run the python file.
Once it is finished, it will change `string_1` value to 11 and repeat the process. Then to 12 and so on until it reaches 20 as defined in the previous step.

Comment: so why not pass it as an argument in the python script?

Comment: Or have the python script prompt for the values? Also, you write *"clueless about lower/upper bound and spacing"*. Please show some examples of what you mean. Are you trying to ensure users don't input an out-of-range value? What does *"spacing"* mean? Please update your question to resolve these issues rather than reply in comments.  Finally, your sample `bash/sed` looks like a good start. You can chain multiple replacments in one `sed` invocation, i.e. `sed -k "s/first/first$usrr1/; s/second/second$usr2/" file` . Be carefule about using the `g` (global). Good luck.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments. I've added few extras to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 1):

this works on my mac. Replace your sed command with this line:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/string_1=.*$/string_1='"$user_value"'/' file.py
```

explanation:

- `-i` on the mac wants an backup extension. `-t ''` says do not create a backup
- `.*$` is needed to replace the whole line.
- single quotes are needed because of the $-character inside the regex
- `g` at the end is not need, because you want to replace just time per line

Comment: if you prefere gnu-sed, you can install it with `brew install gnu-sed`. it will install gsed as the gnu-version of sed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried but it doesn't change the test.py file that contains string_1=. Even after provided the user value, the test.py still has string_1= with no value after the = sign